# downloading a list of urls

Tags: file-system, windows, cache, powershell

I wrote this quick (lots of googling) and dirty (I hope not too dirty) script to download a URL list with a win32 wget port and save them as files with the url as the name to use as a "poor man's url cache" for another program.

It works (tested ~200k links), but I wonder if I did progress management right (it was a power shell feature I wanted to test with this kind of task) and if there are other things I could improve (or make more readable/reduce script length) and/or unexpected failure points.

It is my first time using powershell like this ... please be gentle ;P

```
param ([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$target = 'default'); cd $PSScriptRoot;

$enableProgress = $true;

#if ($enableProgress){

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$urlPAth = "$( pwd )\url_$target.txt";

$baseCrawlPath = "$( pwd )\crawl_data\$target";

if (![System.IO.File]::Exists($urlPath))
{
    Write-Error "missing list file"; exit -1
}

$foo = (mkdir $baseCrawlPath 2> $null);

Write-Progress -Id 13431 -Activity "Load database..." -PercentComplete -1 -Status "Reading file: $urlPath"
$totalLines = (gc ".\url_$target.txt" | ? { $_.Trim() -ne '' }).Count;
Write-Progress -Id 13431 -Activity "Load database..." -Completed

$totalCounter = 0;
$retMax = 10;
$interGetSeconds = 3;

$skipExisting = $true;

[IO.File]::ReadLines($urlPath) | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne '' } | ForEach-Object {
    $totalCounter++;

    #$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$totalLines || $totalCounter"
    # i scrapped this because wget percentage hijacks the title

    if ($enableProgress)
    {
        Write-Progress -Id 1 -Activity "DOWNLOAD - ($target)" -Status "Item $totalCounter of $totalLines" -PercentComplete (($totalCounter / $totalLines) * 100);
    }

    $theUrl = $_.Trim(); $retCount = 0;
    $fileName = $theUrl;
    # I url encode invalid path characters so that the url is preserved when url-decoding all files in folder
    [IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() | foreach { $fileName = $fileName.Replace([String]$_,[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($_)) }
    $filePath = "$baseCrawlPath\$fileName"; # echo $filePath; # debug

    $keepTrying = ($retCount -lt $retMax);
    # $keepTrying = $true; # debug

    $fExists = $false;
    if ($skipExisting)
    {
        $fExists = [System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath);
    }
    if ($fExists)
    {
        $errored = $false; $keepTrying = $false
    }

    while ($keepTrying)
    {
        $retCount++; 
        $keepTrying = ($retCount -lt $retMax);

        $rtPct = (($retCount/$retMax)*100);

        if ($rtPct -gt 100)
        {
            $rtPct = -1
        }
        $rtPct = -1

        if ($enableProgress)
        {
            Write-Progress -Id 2 -ParentId 1 -Activity "WGET [$_]" -Status "Attempt $retCount of $retMax" -PercentComplete $rtPct
        }

        $wgOut = '';

        # $stderrFile = New-TemporaryFile; $stdoutOutput = cmd /c ver '&' dir \nosuch 2>$stderrFile; $stderrOutput = Get-Content $stdErrFile; Remove-Item $stderrFile

        # wget.exe -N "$_"; // timestamping was my initial idea but apparently I can't use urls as filenames

        wget.exe "$_" -O "$filePath"; 
        $wreq = $true; # enable wait

        # i failed at putting stdout and stderr in a variable...
        #Invoke-Expression "C:\IncludePath\wget.exe \"$_\" -O \"$filePath\"" -OutVariable wgOut -ErrorVariable wgOut
        #echo (-join('C:\IncludePath\wget.exe',' "',$_,'"',' -O "',$filePath,'"'));
        #$stderrFile = New-TemporaryFile; $stdoutOutput = Invoke-Expression (-join('C:\IncludePath\wget.exe',' "',$_,'"',' -O "',$filePath,'"')) 2>$stderrFile; $stderrOutput = Get-Content $stdErrFile; Remove-Item $stderrFile

        $errored = ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0); #  if($errored){pause} # debug

        if ($errored)
        {
            #echo $stderrOutput; // initial idea was to have streams in variables to print only in case of errors.
            #echo $stdoutOutput;

            For ($iTimeCounter1 = ($interGetSeconds*$retCount + 3)*5; $iTimeCounter1 -gt 0; $iTimeCounter1--) {
                if ($enableProgress)
                {
                    Write-Progress -Id 4 -ParentId 2 -Activity "ZEN MEDITATION ..." -Status "WGET ERROR CODE: $LASTEXITCODE" -SecondsRemaining $iTimeCounter1;
                }
                Start-Sleep 1;
            }
            if ($enableProgress)
            {
                Write-Progress -Id 4 -ParentId 2 -Activity "ZEN MEDITATION ..." -Completed
            }
            #pause # debug
        }
        else
        {
            if ($enableProgress)
            {
                Write-Progress -Id 2 -ParentId 1 -Activity "WGET [$_]" -Status "Done. Attempt n. $retCount." -PercentComplete -1
            }
            break;
        }

    } # END WHILE


    if ($wreq) # delay requests
    {
        For ($iTimeCounter1 = $interGetSeconds; $iTimeCounter1 -gt 0; $iTimeCounter1--) {
            if ($enableProgress)
            {
                Write-Progress -Id 2 -ParentId 1 -Activity "WGET [$_]" -Status "Done. Attempt n. $retCount." -CurrentOperation "Attesa tra una richiesta e l'altra..." -SecondsRemaining $iTimeCounter1;
            }
            Start-Sleep 1;
        }
    };


    if ($enableProgress)
    {
        Write-Progress -Id 2 -ParentId 1 -Activity "WGET [$_]" -Status "Done. Attempt n. $retCount." -Completed
    }

    if ($errored)
    {
        pause
    } # debug

}
```

Comment: You can even download files without using wget even showing the progressbar `Invoke-WebRequest Url -OutFile OutputFile`